# How to send data through activities and save it, for further use?

Tags: android

I wand to create an Android app that has multiple activities where I pass in data and then send it to MainActivity. I wantend to do this by creating intents to pass the data and then store it using savedInstanceState. 
It works well if I pass the InformationA but then when I send data InfomationB with another intent InformationA that was stored is erased. 
I also tried using shared preferences.

How can i fix that and why is the InformationA erasing?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String order = "Order \n";
String Order1;
String Order2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView warzywa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.warzywa);
    warzywa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View View){
            Intent idź_w = new Intent(MainActivity.this, vegetables_activity.class);
            startActivity(idź_w);
        }
    });
    TextView owoced = (TextView) findViewById(owoce);
    owoced.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View View){
            Intent idź_w = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Owoce.class);
            startActivity(idź_w);
        }
    });

    Button wysyłka = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zamówienie_całkowite);

    wysyłka.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View View){
              if (Order1==null && getIntent().getExtras().getString("WhatO")!=null)
              Order1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("WhatO");
               if (Order2==null && getIntent().getExtras().getString("WhatV")!=null)
              Order2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("WhatV");    
              order = order + Order1 + Order2;
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + order , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("Order1", Order1);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Order2", Order2);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Order1 = savedInstanceState.getString("Order1");
    Order2 = savedInstanceState.getString("Order2");
}}
```

1 child activity

```
public class vegetables_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
String Order = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_warzywa);
    final ArrayList<Produkt> vegetables = new ArrayList<>();
    vegetables.add(new Produkt("tomatoe", 0));
    vegetables.add(new Produkt("onion", 0));
    vegetables.add(new Produkt("potatoe", 0));

    New_Adapter adapter = new New_Adapter(this, vegetables);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_vegetables);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button order = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zamówienie_warzywne);
    order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View View) {
            for (int z = 0; z < vegetables.size(); z++) {
                if (vegetables.get(z).getMquantity() != 0) {
                    Order = "" + Order + vegetables.get(z).getmNazwa_Warzywa() + " razy " + vegetables.get(z).getMquantity() + "\n";
                }
            }
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(vegetables_activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("WhatV", Order);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

2 child activity

```
public class Owoce extends AppCompatActivity {
String Order_Owoce = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_warzywa);
    final ArrayList<Produkt> vegetables = new ArrayList<>();
    vegetables.add(new Produkt("apple", 0));
    vegetables.add(new Produkt("banana", 0));
    vegetables.add(new Produkt("peach", 0));

    New_Adapter adapter = new New_Adapter(this, vegetables);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_vegetables);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button order = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zamówienie_warzywne);
    order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View View) {
            for (int z = 0; z < vegetables.size(); z++) {
                if (vegetables.get(z).getMquantity() != 0) {
                    Order_Owoce = "" + Order_Owoce + vegetables.get(z).getmNazwa_Warzywa() + " razy " + vegetables.get(z).getMquantity() + "\n";
                }
            }
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Owoce.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("WhatO", Order_Owoce);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: Are you storing data into the ```Bundle``` wirh the same keys? This would overwrite the original data. Do post code for further insight.

Comment: Added relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try an array. Put each piece of relevant information in a specific place in the array (which should be transferred between activities with the intent), and also send the index of that piece of information with the intent so that the receiving Activity knows where to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments in a Bundle from Activity to another Activity when you declare your intent.

See example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("argKey", argValue);
```

But be aware that the Bundle can only store up to 1MB, If I'm not mistaken, so when you need to pass a huge array for example, try different approaches like SharedPreferences or save the data you wish to preserve in a DataManager singleton class and retrieve it when you need.

Comment: I tried doing that, however it seems to me that when I pass intent for the 2 time the informations that I stored with savedInstanceState seem to vanish